# Perl: Net::LDAP::LDIF moddn example

Tags: perl, ldap, ldif

I'm looking for **example code** howto change the DN or rather the RDN with CPAN's Net::LDAP. Important: I don't want to make this change to the server directly, but **generate a LDIF file**! There's only a moddn function in Net::LDAP, but not in the LDIF module. Nevertheless I read somewhere on the internet, that it's possible to create such a LDIF file.

Probably I have to use **Net::LDAP::Entry's moddn** function but I haven't found a way to write this change to a LDIF file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for examples of what the LDIF should look like, see this: [moving and renaming entries](https://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/mastering-moddn/)